# discord music bot error, ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel in this server

Tags: python, bots, discord

i make a command for my discord bot, that play some sound from video on youtube. This function work good, if you call her one time, but on the second time i get error that my bot already connected into this voice channel.
so i tried to disconnect the bot after he play the video, but it didn't work.

The Function:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def video(ctx, msg):
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()   
    await vc.disconnect() #not good, the video not playing
```

error without `await vc.disconnect()` :

```
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel in this server
```

thank for helpers ^^ have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [how danny does it in the examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/playlist.py). Otherwise your issues can be addressed by [checking if the bot is already connected to a servers voice channel](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.is_voice_connected) and second not disconnecting once you do `player.start()` since this does not block for the [stream player](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.create_stream_player) to finish playing at which point you disconnect from the voice channel and the stream just dies.